# Que significa si coloco action:0 en el atributo data cuando uso ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

No se si formule bien la pregunta jeje, me refiero a que significa este pedazo de codigo?

```js
 $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: _url,
            data: {action: 0, search_head: search_head, chngroup: chngroup, language: language},
            async: false, dataType: 'json', success: function(data) {
                var n = data.length;
                if (n === 0) {
                    $('<center></center>').appendTo('#css-interno-li-grid');
                    return false;
                }
                if (typeof specialGrid === "undefined") {
                    if (n === 1) {
                        Products.Form(data);
                    } else {
                        Products.Grid(data);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (n === 1) {
                        Products.SpecialGrid(data);
                    } else {
                        Products.SpecialGrid(data);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Me interesa saber que significa donde se coloco action:0
significa que esta peticion esta siendo enviada al mismo archivo o que??
si, este codigo no es mio y si, soy novata con ajax jeje

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con el archivo al que se manda, estás enviando un dato (parámetro) con nombre "action" y valor "0". Deberías pasarte por la [documentación de jQuery para AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) y familiarizarte con cómo funciona.

Answer (score 0):

La opción `data` en `Ajax` significa que son los datos que vas a enviar en tu caso action es el nombre de la variable que vas a enviar y el 0 es el valor que le estas mandando en esa variable.

Siempre se envian `nombrevar`:`valorvar`